# how to Create Chess Clock using Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have created a chess application.But I am trying to create chess clock in server side.I have already implemented chess clock in client side but its not working well on some cases.so anybody help me how to create  chess clock in nodejs(server side).so I want to get timing from server.

Comment: Currently your question is too broad or unclear, and because free code writing service is not really the goal of SO, it's unlikely someone will write all the code for you without more details. There are many ways to time things, so you should show what you tried and/or be much more specific about what you want.

Comment: @Kaddath I just want to idea not code.so problem is how to manage server clock for chess game.where user and opponent play a game and a clock on both side is runing .if user make first move than user clock is pause and opponent clock is run.and when opponent makes his move than oppenent clock is pause and user clock is run.so this type of clock i want to impement from server side .clock is runing on server side and socket emit the time.